# update database's table in WCF service using EF

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I want to update my database table in wcf web service. but I got 2 error. first I can't change  string to datetime. I sent "1/1/1991" but i got error. Second, I can't update my table. How can I fix it?

```
myentities db = new myentities();   
 public bool EditPerson(int uid,string _name,string bdate,string adr,string cty,string email,string tel,string pass)
        {
            DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(bdate, "yyyy-MM-dd",null); //Error

            var person = db.Person.FirstOrDefault(x => x.pID == uid);
            if (person != null)
            {
                Person pt = new Person();
                pt.pName = _name;
                pt.birthDate = myDate;
                pt.adress = adr;
                pt.city = cty;
                pt.email = email;
                pt.tel = int.Parse(tel);

                db.Entry(person).CurrentValues.SetValues(pt);
                db.SaveChanges();  //Error
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Error : **The client was unable to process the request due to an internal error.**

```
Server stack trace:
   location: System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   location: System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   location: System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   location: System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   location: System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   location: System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   location: System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   location: IService.EditPerson(Int32 uid, String _name, String bdate, String adr, String cty, String email, String tel, String pass)
   location: ServiceClient.EditPerson(Int32 uid, String _name, String bdate, String adr, String cty, String email, String tel, String pass)
```

Comment: "I got error" is absolutely useless. What error? Where? The same goes for "I can't update my table" - why not?

Comment: I can't update, `db.SaveChanges()` gives error.

Comment: Really? Error? I already wrote: We cannot help you if you don't tell us what error you get.

Comment: Error : The client was unable to process the request due to an internal error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`DateTime.ParseExact` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

In your case, they are not. If your string is `1/1/1991`, then you need to use `d/M/yyyy` (I assume first one is day) format instead.

And you might need to use [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) because [`/` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning of *replace me with the current culture date seperator*. When you use null as a [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IFormatProvider.aspx), this method uses your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If your current culture thread has `/` as a [`DateSeperator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that's fine to use `null`.

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(bdate, "d/M/yyyy",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I can not say anything about your update error because I'm not familiar with Entity Framework too much.